# Have Button trigger UpdateSource on Control Binding without codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Say I have two fields that contain values and I want the ViewModel to only update when a save button is pressed.

From my research the main two ways of having a button trigger updates to fields is to either have codebehind calling updateSource() on the binding expressions or to add increased complexity to the ViewModel in order to handle intermediate values.

Is there really no way to trigger updateSource using only XAML?

Comment: The intended way uses the command pattern. 1) The ViewModel exposes commands. Propably in a few collections 2) Various UI Elements can be used to *represent* those commands. Those elements can be Buttons, MenuItem, Hotkeys, Propably Smartphone Gestures and whatever else is "in" for UI design right now.  | I think I found a example using ICommand as basis: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example But IIRC, there are other ways too.

Comment: It may be possible, look for behavior triggers in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to trigger the update from XAML, but you can build your own. For example, you could use the infrastructure set up by [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf).

First, create an action you can execute in reply to a trigger from XAML. This action is configured by a Target/PropertyName pair. Given this information, the Action knows which Property to update in which Element (in your case, the Text property in your TextBox). These properties need to be set in XAML (see below).

The Invoke-method is invoked by the corresponding trigger declared in XAML (in your case, the Button.Click event, again, see below), you don't invoke it yourself in code.

```
    public class UpdateBindingAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
    {
        public FrameworkElement Target
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Target), typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(UpdateBindingAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));


        public string PropertyName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(UpdateBindingAction), new PropertyMetadata(null));


        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            if (Target == null)
                return;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName))
                return;

            var propertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(PropertyName, Target.GetType(), Target.GetType());
            if (propertyDescriptor == null)
                return;

            Target.GetBindingExpression(propertyDescriptor.DependencyProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
    }
```

Then, create a binding in XAML that doesn't update automatically

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="200" Text="{Binding String1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txt2" Width="200" Text="{Binding String2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

Last, create a button that contains an EventTrigger for the Click-Event, which executes the UpdateSourceAction(s). The "b:" namespace is `xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"` (from Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf), the "local:" namespace is the one where you put the UpdateBindingAction.

```
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Update">
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <local:UpdateBindingAction Target="{Binding ElementName=txt1}" PropertyName="Text" />
                    <local:UpdateBindingAction Target="{Binding ElementName=txt2}" PropertyName="Text" />
                    <!-- ... -->
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

There's some generic built-in triggers (EventTrigger, PropertyChangedTrigger, ...) and actions (ChangePropertyAction, CallMethodAction, ...), but it is very possible to implement your own additions, like this one.